# Обновление отметок отслеживания изменений сущностей в EF6 на изменении отношений

Tags: c#, entity-framework

В приложении используется EF6 по модели Code First. Для ряда доменных объектов реализован интерфейс *IModificationTracking*:

```
interface IModificationTracking
{
    DateTime RecordCreationTimestamp { get; set; }

    DateTime RecordModificationTimestamp { get; set; }

}
```

Для обновления перечисленных полей метод сохранения контекста данных дополнен следующим образом:

```
public override int SaveChanges()
{
    DateTime timestamp = DateTime.Now;

    var entries = ChangeTracker.Entries()
        .Where(entry => entry.Entity is IModificationTracking)
        .ToList();

    IModificationTracking x;

        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            var state = entry.State;

            switch (state)
            {
                case EntityState.Added:
                    entry.SetPropertyValue(nameof(x.RecordCreationTimestamp), timestamp);
                    entry.SetPropertyValue(nameof(x.RecordModificationTimestamp), timestamp);
                    break;
                case EntityState.Modified:
                    entry.SetPropertyValue(nameof(x.RecordModificationTimestamp), timestamp);
                    break;
                default:
                    break;
            }
        }

    return base.SaveChanges();
}
```

При этом используется статический класс *DbEntityEntryEx*:

```
public static class DbEntityEntryEx
{
    public static void SetPropertyValue<T>(this DbEntityEntry entry, string propertyName, T timestamp)
    {
        entry.Property(propertyName).CurrentValue = timestamp;
    }
}
```

Указанная реализация подсмотрена в [этом ответе](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43428887/update-created-and-modified-date-fields-in-dbcontext-class-with-entity-framework).

Проблема заключается в том, что для комплексных сущностей, который строятся по связям через навигационные свойства моделей, такой метод отслеживания не приводит к фиксации обновления записей в случае, когда меняются только лишь связи между объектами (*EntityState* в этом случае остается *Unchanged*, вот [обсуждение](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11670212/entity-framework-wont-detect-changes-of-navigation-properties) ).

Хотелось бы подсказки как расширить регистрацию изменений с учетом не только изменения свойств, но из и изменения отношений сущностей.

Comment: Возможно, я недостаточно ясно сформулировал вопрос: меня интересует не сохранение изменений объектов как таковое (с этим никаких проблем нет, EF справляется и с мониторингом EntityState и RelationshipState), а модификация отметки даты и времени изменения основной сущности в момент сохранения контекста. Этого не происходит в моем примере, если отсматривать EntityState, потому что когда меняется только связь, а не собственные свойства - EntityState не становится Modified. Поэтому и прошу помочь учитывать и изменение отношений :) GraphDiff тоже сработает, только по-моему это оверинжиниринг :)

Comment: Да, еще добавлю DBContext привязан к времени жизни экрана (приложение локальное с SQLite в качестве БД), сущности изначально присоединены в контексту и ведется автоматическая регистрация изменений.